# Configure script for Git 2.27.0 does not find libpcre2 automatically

Tags: git, installation

I'm trying to build Git 2.27.0 from source with PCRE2 support (for the [`--perl-regexp` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---perl-regexp) to `git log`). However, the configure script for Git doesn't find the files from libpcre2 unless I give it the path explicitly. Can anyone tell why? Is there something I should change to allow the configure script to detect libpcre2 automatically?

## Details: automatic detection

Here's what I tried to get Git to detect libpcre2 automatically. I ran the following commands, shown with partial output:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/git/git.git git-from-source
...
$ cd git-from-source
...
$ git checkout v2.27.0
...
HEAD is now at b3d7a52fac Git 2.27
$ make configure
GIT_VERSION = 2.27.0
    GEN configure
$ ./configure --help
...
  --with-libpcre2         support Perl-compatible regexes via libpcre2
                          (default is NO)
                          ARG can be also prefix for libpcre library and
                          headers
...
$ ./configure --with-libpcre2 | grep -i pcre
checking for pcre2_config_8 in -lpcre2-8... no
$ make -j $(nproc)
...
$ ( cd t; sh t4202-log.sh | grep -i pcre )
...
ok 32 # skip log -F -E --perl-regexp --grep=<pcre> uses PCRE (missing PCRE)
$ bin-wrappers/git log --perl-regexp --grep '^\w' -n 1
fatal: cannot use Perl-compatible regexes when not compiled with USE_LIBPCRE
```

As far as I can tell, my environment is configured such that Git *should* be able to find libpcre2:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags libpcre2-8
-I/custom_path/usr/include  
$ pcre2-config --cflags
-I/custom_path/usr/include  
$ pkg-config --libs libpcre2-8
-L/custom_path/usr/lib -lpcre2-8
$ pcre2-config --libs8
-L/custom_path/usr/lib -lpcre2-8
$ pcre2-config --version
10.35
$ ls -1 /custom_path/usr/include/*pcre*
/custom_path/usr/include/pcre2.h
/custom_path/usr/include/pcre2posix.h
$ ls -1 /custom_path/usr/lib/*pcre*
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-8.a
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-8.la
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0.10.0
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-posix.a
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-posix.la
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-posix.so
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-posix.so.2
/custom_path/usr/lib/libpcre2-posix.so.2.0.3
```

(`custom_path` stands for a perfectly normal but nonstandard directory whose exact path I have obscured for privacy reasons)

## Details: manual detection

If I fully clean the build directory and repeat the above procedure except that I pass the path to libpcre2 as an argument to `--with-pcre2`, then things work fine:

```
$ git clean -xdf .
...
$ make configure
GIT_VERSION = 2.27.0
    GEN configure
$ ./configure --with-libpcre2=/custom_path/usr | grep -i pcre
checking for pcre2_config_8 in -lpcre2-8... yes
$ make -j $(nproc)
...
$ ( cd t; sh t4202-log.sh | grep -i pcre )
...
ok 32 - log -F -E --perl-regexp --grep=<pcre> uses PCRE
$ bin-wrappers/git log --perl-regexp --grep '^\w' -n 1
commit b3d7a52fac39193503a0b6728771d1bf6a161464 (HEAD, tag: v2.27.0)
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun May 31 23:03:57 2020

    Git 2.27

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```